# Diagonalise a sparse block diagonal matrix scipy

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a large sparse block diagonal matrix that I want to diagonalise. I can diagonalise the individual block diagonals, but this means doing an eigendecomposition in many smallish (6x6 up to 15x15) matrices, and stacking all the results in an sparse matrix. This works, but the size of the loop makes it unfeasible. Here is my loop-based code, which shows that you can use this to reconstruct the original matrix. In my case, I am after doing something else than just a reconstruction, but this in my case it just means that I do something with the eigenvalues within the loop.

I haven't got experience with Numba or Cython, and I don't know whether they'll be be useful in this context.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp
# A fast block_diag for equally sized blocks
# Currently a PR in scipy: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/5619)
from utils import block_diag

n_pixels = 10 # Number of elements
n_p = 7 # Number of elements per block
# Main diagonal of each block
sigma = np.array([0.12, 0.7, 0.0959, 0.15, 1.5, 0.2, 0.5])  
# The individual block definition
little_p = np.diag ( sigma**2).astype(np.float32)
# Add some off-diagonal elements. For fun.
little_p[5,2] = 0.8862*0.0959*0.2
little_p[2,5] = 0.8862*0.0959*0.2
# Stack a large number of these in a block diagonal matrix
xlist = [little_p for m in xrange(n_pixels)]
A = block_diag(xlist, dtype=np.float32)

# Try to reconstruct using diagonalisation of individual blocks
blocks = []
A = A.tolil()
for i in xrange(n_pixels):
    M = A[(i*n_p):((i+1)*n_p), (i*n_p):((i+1)*n_p)].todense()
    s,u = np.linalg.eigh(M)
    blocks.append (  u.dot(np.diag(s).dot(u.T)) )

B = block_diag(blocks, dtype=np.float32)
np.allclose(B.todense(), A.todense()) # Should be True
```

Comment: `scipy/sparse` does use `cython` to create compiled code for some key operations, for example the various forms of multiplication.  `scikit-learn` has added some of its own cython based sparse utilities.

Comment: How's this import `block_diag` different from `sparse.block_diag` (which delegates to `bmat`?

Comment: `block_diag`, whether from this patch, or working just with `bmat` collects the `coo` attributes of the component matrices, concatenates them with the appropriate offsets, and makes a new `coo` matrix.  What's that `eigh` and `dot` supposed to be doing?

Comment: @hpaulj The patch is a speed-up for block diagonals where all blocks are of the same size. If you don't use it, creating a large sparse matrix is very slow, it hasn't been yet accepted into scipy main AFAIK. The eigh and dot are there as a placeholder to put something in the loop.